# Counting unique students

Tags: word-problem

A Kaggle.com question to fight spam is:

> A total of 61 students are taking a probability course. 33 are
>   majoring in mathematics, 29 in statistics, 18 in finance, 17 majoring
>   in mathematics and statistics, 9 majoring in mathematics and finance,
>   10 majoring in statistics and finance, and 7 majoring in all three.
>   What is the number of people not majoring in either mathematics,
>   statistics, or finance?

My approach was to work backwards, by assuming that 7 is a unique number, then subtracting it from the 2-major group figures, then subtracting the sum of 7 + the 2-major group figures from the sum of `33 + 29 + 18` to figure out how many math, stats, and finance student to subtract from the original figure of 61.

I finally got it. My initial approach was correct, but apparently I must've punched in a wrong number somewhere along the line.

My logic was:

```
Let a = mathematics
Let b = statistics
Let c = finance
```

- 7 unique students major in a, b, and c
- 3 additional unique students major in b and c (but not a; i.e. 7 of the 10 in the 2nd-to-last group described are the same 7 in a, b, and c)
- 2 additional unique students major in a and c (but not b)
- 10 additional unique students major in a and b (but not c)
- There are `33 + 29 + 18 = 80` students described as majoring in a, b, or c, thus this count is of non-distinct records (`80 > 61`)
- Of the 33 majoring in a, `33 - 7 - 10 - 2 = 14` are majoring exclusively in a
- Of the 29 majoring in b, `29 - 7 - 10 - 3 = 9` are majoring exclusively in b
- Of the 18 majoring in c, `18 - 7 - 2 - 3 = 6` are majoring exclusively in c
- `14 + 9 + 6 = 29` are majoring exclusively in a, b, or c and `7 + 3 + 2 + 10 = 22` unique students are majoring in some combination thereof
- Of the 61 students, `61 - 29 - 22 = 10` are not majoring in either mathematics, statistics, or finance

I actually had to do this twice to pass their check, probably because I answer the question above wrong before getting it right.

---

*In the 2nd permutation it went like this:*

- 63 total students
- 8 unique students major in math, stats, and finance
- 13 additional unique students major in stats and finance
- 10 additional unique students major in math and finance (but not stats)
- 7 additional unique students major in math and stats (but not finance)
    therefore 28 unique multi-majors of math,stats, and/or finance
- There are `31 + 32 + 36 = 99` students described as majoring in math, stats, or finance, thus this count is of non-distinct records (`99 > 63`)
- Of the 31 majoring in math,  `31 - 8 - 10 - 7 = 6` are majoring exclusively in math
- Of the 32 majoring in stats, `32 - 8 - 13 - 7 = 4` are majoring exclusively in stats
- Of the 36 majoring in finan, `36 - 8 -  13 - 10 = 5` are majoring exclusively in finance
- `6 + 4 + 5 = 15` are majoring exclusively in math, stats, or finance and `8 + 13 + 10 + 7 = 38` unique students are majoring in some combination thereof
- Of the 63 students, `63 - 15 - 38 = 10` are not majoring in either mathematics, statistics, or finance

Oy vey! What happened to the anti-spam questions where you click all the pictures containing pizza?

On my first pass I had 1 number off in 1 equation and got an answer of 12. Kaggle.com actually did accept this as the correct answer for some reason, but @N.F. Taussig has convinced me that the answer is 10 not 12 in his comments and solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Not by that name. I clicked the link but it appears to be broken. Perhaps you could explain in an answer?

Comment: If you can undo your latest edit, you should since it is expected that you show your own attempt to solve the problem when you post a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) states that

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

where $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in set $S$.  Thus, the number of students in the class majoring in at least one of the three subjects is

\begin{align*}
|A \cup B \cup C| & = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|\\
                  & = 33 + 29 + 18 - 17 - 9 - 10 + 7\\
                  & = 51
\end{align*}
Since there are a total of $61$ students in the class, there are $10$ students taking the probability class who are not majoring in at least one of the subjects mathematics, statistics, and finance.

Comment: Ah! thanks for the updated link. I follow your logic, but unfortunately 10 was also an incorrect answer...

Comment: @Hack-R The answer is definitely 10. (Just did problem with a Venn diagram by filling in regions, also got 51 in at least one of the three majors.

Comment: Thanks for the help! +1. I don't know why Kaggle.com accepted a slightly wrong answer and got me all confused. I guess they had a range around the correct solution to allow for small mistakes or something.